# sqlmap and encoding databases

Tags: python, sql, oracle, code-injection

hey guys i have a problem on sqlmap : 
"cannot properly display Unicode characters inside Windows OS command prompt (http://bugs.python.org/issue1602). All unhandled occurances will result in replacement with '?' character. Please, find proper character representation inside corresponding output files."
example : available databases [*] "ذ–HRL\X8BVUJ"

please help me :(

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33475373/3027266

Comment: Here is some more https://community.oracle.com/thread/600575